# Bootstrap Dropdown menu not popping up

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I know there has been a couple of similar questions but they didn't seem to resolve the issue for me. 
I am trying to set up a page (with python/flask but that shouldn't be relevant) and i am using bootstrap.
I am very new to all this but tried to create some dummy navigation bar so copied the nav class from bootstrap examples pages. 
However, the dropdown menu doesn't pop up (it does nothing). 
Do you have any suggestion?
Below is my entire page html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

    HOME

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add jQuery before bootstraph.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only using Bootstrap Script.

You need to add jquery Script for Navbar (i would suggest to use popper script as well)

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The same is also mentioned on [Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: You are a life saver! to be honest i did add the jquery but not the popper and that didn't work, maybe i had the order wrong but now it does work ok.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the list of components that requires JavaScript. Source - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/

- Alerts for dismissing
- Buttons for toggling states and checkbox/radio functionality
- Carousel for all slide behaviors, controls, and indicators
- Collapse for toggling visibility of content
- **Dropdowns for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper.js)**
- Modals for displaying, positioning, and scroll behavior
- Navbar for extending our Collapse plugin to implement responsive behavior
- Tooltips and popovers for displaying and positioning (also requires Popper.js)
- Scrollspy for scroll behavior and navigation updates

So you need to add these 3 scripts inside the body of HTML(In the same sequence).

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```