# Can't Get Modals to Work using Bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been having an issue getting modals to work.

To rule out problems with my own modals, I've copied the modal example code from the Bootstrap site into a new HTML file, linked to the CDN and it doesn't work. The button is there but clicking it does nothing. The code works on the Bootstrap site, and I've copied and pasted the same code, and it's not working locally in my new HTML file.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
    </button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As said above, the code does exactly what you'd expect on the Bootstrap site. Just not when I use it. I've tried Chrome, Edge and Firefox. Same thing.

Comment: I believe you need load jquery as well.

Comment: Open the Developer Tools. Look at the Console. **Read the error message**. It tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I have this at the bottom of the page:     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: jQuery must come first. so add jQuery before bootstrap.js. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669636/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-popping-up/52669682#52669682

Comment: @daz-wuk your code is alos working.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise JQuery had to come first. I've always seen it included at the bottom of the Body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order for the Scripts seems to be wrong.

The correct order should be

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

1. Jquery
2. Popper (depending on your usage, it maybe optional)
3. Bootstrap.

The same is also mentioned on [Bootstrap Site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)