# Why aren't all of my Bootstrap 4 carousel links working?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am in the process of updating a website that I administer to use Bootstrap 4. I want a carousel on the index page that advertises upcoming events. My events are defined in a JSON file and the HTML is constructed via various PHP routines that read this JSON. Therefore, all items in the carousel are constructed the same.

There are 3 events displayed initially, and further blocks of 3 become available when using the carousel controls.

On the face of things, everything is working OK - the controls, scrolling to the next or previous block of 3, and so on.  The problem is the links. Clicking on the 'See Details' button of any of the first 5 events takes you to the secondary page and displays details of the event as expected. But clicking the button of event 6 onwards takes you to the last event the secondary page.  All links referenced by the carousel exist on the secondary page.

The following appear in the HEAD section of the page

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.min.css'> 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/indexCarousel.css' />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script> 
<script src='scripts/bootstrap.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/bjqs-1.3.min.js' ></script>
```

The following is the page source of the body of the generated page (I've omitted events 4-9 for brevity - I'm sure you can figure out what it looks like):

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-10 col-center m-auto'>
      <div id='myCarousel' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel' data-interval='0'>
        <div class='carousel-inner'>
          <div class='item carousel-item active'>
            <div class='row'>
              <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='thumb-wrapper'>
                  <div class='img-box'>
                    <img src='images/photo1.jpg' class='img-responsive img-fluid' alt=''>
                  </div>
                  <div class='thumb-content'>
                    <h4>Description of photo1</h4>
                    <p>some other text</p>
                    <a href='secondpage.php#link1' class='btn btn-primary'>See details<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='thumb-wrapper'>
                  <div class='img-box'>
                    <img src='images/photo2.jpg' class='img-responsive img-fluid' alt=''>
                  </div>
                  <div class='thumb-content'>
                    <h4>Description of photo2</h4>
                    <p>some other text</p>
                    <a href='secondpage.php#link2' class='btn btn-primary'>See details<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='thumb-wrapper'>
                  <div class='img-box'>
                    <img src='images/photo3.jpg' class='img-responsive img-fluid' alt=''>
                  </div>
                  <div class='thumb-content'>
                    <h4>Description of photo3</h4>
                    <p>some other text</p>
                    <a href='secondpage.php#link3' class='btn btn-primary'>See details<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  <!-- end of row -->
          </div>  <!-- end of carousel-item -->

          <div class='item carousel-item'>
            <div class='row'>
              ...
              <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <div class='thumb-wrapper'>
                  <div class='img-box'>
                    <img src='images/photo10.jpg' class='img-responsive img-fluid' alt=''>
                  </div>
                  <div class='thumb-content'>
                    <h4>Description of photo10</h4>
                    <p>some other text</p>
                    <a href='secondpage.php#link10' class='btn btn-primary'>See details<i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class='carousel-control left carousel-control-prev' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='prev'><i class='fa fa-angle-left'></i></a>
        <a class='carousel-control right carousel-control-next' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='next'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end of row -->
</div>  <!-- end of container -->
```

Any pointers as to why links 6 onwards aren't working will be gratefully received. I've been scratching my head for a couple of weeks and this is almost the final piece of the re-brand so I want to get it working.

Comment: H do you get any error messages in the console log?
Also do all your carousels have different ids?

Comment: Could it have something to do with you not using relative references for your `href` attributes? For instance, should it be `href='/secondpage.php#link10'`?

Comment: @RichardHousham It has the same name because it's supposed to be one carousel with, maybe, 10-12 photos, displayed 3 at a time. Is that not possible?  Why would the first two items of the second page work but the third and remaining pages not?   I've not noticed any error messages but will take another look when I get a chance.

Comment: @BYates Maybe, I'll try it. But why would the first 5 work?

Comment: I doubt if it will work with 5 as well. Lot of people usually forget adding `popper.js` cdn file. 

As stated in Bootstrap docs, You need import popper.js file as well 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

For the **correct order of scripts** refer to my answer on this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669636/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-popping-up/52669682#52669682

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with your carousel, but instead with the page you want to link to and the anchors there. Please remove the html for the carousel and add the html of your '_display/secondpage.php'. See this for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/8pc60xz9/

Comment: OK, been playing around and can confirm a few things...   (1) No errors in the console log,   (2) putting the slash in the HREF link breaks it i.e. "page not found",   (3) Adding Popper.js makes no difference.    I have tried outputting the page source HTML directly from my PHP routine rather than generating the source as I usually and (no surprises) it fails in exactly the same way i.e. first 5 links are fine, remainder all go the end of the secondary page.   The links are correct but I'll be trying to follow @Sirence suggestion when I get time.

Comment: So, (eventually!)... it turns out that @Sirence was correct in that the fault was with the destination page.  There was another carousel on that page that was somehow interfering with the links (different id).  Anyway, I've redesigned the page and removed that carousel and now all seems to be working.