# How can I run bootstrap examples?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sample

Here is a sample of source code included in index.html file of bootstrap 4.3.1 in path `bootstrap-4.3.1\site\docs\4.3\examples\jumbotron\index.html`. I don't know how to run this in browser?

Do I need to modify it and include external css or there are some tricks for it?

```
---
layout: examples
title: Jumbotron Template
extra_css: "jumbotron.css"
---

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<main role="main">

  <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
      <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>

  </div> <!-- /container -->

</main>

<footer class="container">
  <p>&copy; Company 2017-{{ site.time | date: "%Y" }}</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: You need to have following scripts at the end of body: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669636/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-popping-up/52669682#52669682 

and reference to css in your head tag

Answer (score 0):

Edit your extra css option:

```
---
layout: examples
title: Jumbotron Template
output:
  html_document:
    css: jumbotron.css
---
```

Add the JS scripts to your project or layout.